# What process is text to speech on macOS Monterey?

Tags: operating-system, text-to-speech, macos-monterey

What process is text to speech on macOS Monterey?

Trying to isolate the text to speech process to control the audio volume with audio program.

It use to be a process called "Text to Speech" on Catalina, now it seems to be 'Voiceover' or something else.